# Empty array with empty initializer

Tags: c, sizeof, variable-declaration

How am I to understand this:

```
void Func(double* P, long L) {}
int main(void) {
    double pert[] = {};
    Func(pert, sizeof(pert)/sizeof(pert[0]));
}
```

My compiler complains:   error: use of GNU empty initializer extension. gcc and Clang can compile and run it fine. How is that syntax different from `double pert[]`; or `double *pert`;

In this example, `per`t doesn't even have a [0], so how can `pert[0]` make sense? Yeah, I guess It's the same as `sizeof(double)`.

In particular, the code I'm analyzing uses a lot of `sizeof` on arrays, so I don't want to change `[]` to `*` needlessly;

Comment: You can't create empty arrays in standard C. `double *pert;` is a pointer at all...

Comment: That's not valid C, the message from your compiler could not be more clear. If arrays and pointers would be the same, they would both be called either "arrays" or "pointer".

Answer (score 1):

```
double pert[] = {};
```

is a little of catch-22 case, array is supposed to have at least one element to have size defined or it will be termined from initializer list, but you use empty initializer list, which wasn't supported in standard C and came from C++, it would init declared array members to 0. Gcc would treat it as array of one element, I think.

An expression `pert[anything]` is equivalent of `*(pert + anything)`. In fact you can write `0[pert]`. As long as summ of two arguments of [] would an dereferenceable pointer, that would be legal code (for which you would be crucified by code review team).

To clear things up, pert is NOT pointer, it is name of array that can deteriorate to a pointer to a type of array element, if used in expression where pointer is required. so if you pass array as pointer, you will loose information about array size and sizeof will not work

Comment: So, how does Func() (whose code I don't have) make use of pert ? The passed size is 0, and it cannot enlarge and return anything inside the array, can it ?

Comment: @dargaud excuse me, you can't enlarge array in C or C++! that's abc of c and c++. you have to use a container (ideally), e.g. std::vector  in c++, or use allocated dynamic object in c, getting memory by malloc. What you declared is a static array, its size can't change. To resize allocated memory, realloc is used. You have to save and pass size of allocated memory

Comment: Yeah, so my guess is that that line is just a placeholder: doesn't do anything at the moment, but you can change the function behavior by adding to the initializer. I'll try to get confirmation on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` doesn't have anything to check since the array is wrongly declared.  You need to declare a size of the array in C, or have elements in the array.  You can't have an empty array declaration with no size.

Try `double pert[128];` to create a double array named "pert" with 128 spots.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `double *` creates a *pointer to a `double`*.  This can point to an array element or a single variable.

In contrast, when an array is declared it has to have at least one element and its size must be known.  A definition with an initializer like this:

```
double pert[] = { 4.5, 6,7 };
```

Is allowed because the size of the array can be inferred from the number of elements in the initializer, and that size is greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

`double pert[] = {};`

It is an illegal operation and wont compile.

Use pointer instead `double *pert;` and allocate memory when needed

Comment: Yeah, I know, I'm just trying to understand why it's done this way and what it actually does, so I can replace it with valid code without breaking anything.